# How do I rewrite a line of text in a console project? c++

Tags: c++

I'm working on a c++ console project and i would like to show a percentage without making a new line each time (so that the window doesn't get clogged with thousands of lines).

Is there a way of removing the last line that was printed or something to say that the next time that i output a line it should replace the current line?

Comment: There's many ways of doing this, but most of them are dependent on your host environment (i.e. operating system). What OS are you targeting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I erase the current line printed on console in C ? I am working on a linux system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508490/how-can-i-erase-the-current-line-printed-on-console-in-c-i-am-working-on-a-lin)

Comment: Even though that has the same answer in it, that is based around C whereas i was asking about C++. someone looking for a solution to this in C++ would't necessarily look at C based answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a \r (carriage return) to return the cursor to the beginning of the line:

This works on windows and Linux.

From: [Erase the current printed console line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508490/how-can-i-erase-the-current-line-printed-on-console-in-c-i-am-working-on-a-lin)

You could alternatively use a series of backspaces.

```
string str="Hello!";
cout << str;
cout << string(str.length(),'\b');
cout << "Hello again!";
```

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/25744/

Maybe mark as duplicate? I am really not sure how.

Comment: The little "flag" link under the tags allows you to flag the question for various reasons, including potentially being a duplicate

Comment: Actually, duplicate is a reason for closing, not flagging.

Answer (score 6):

A simple example that I tested on `Linux` would be:

```cpp
std::cout << "Some text to display..." << "\t\r" << std::flush;
```

Here the `\t` adds a tabulation to handle slightly varying string lengths and `\r` sends the cursor back at the start of the line (as mentioned in other answers). 
`std::flush` is required to guarantee that the line is displayed without jumping to the next line.

Answer (score 2):

This is very platform-dependent and terminal-dependent.  But, you may want to look at ncurses for a start: http://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses

For Windows: [How can I overwrite the same portion of the console in a Windows native C++ console app, without using a 3rd Party library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45286/how-can-i-overwrite-the-same-portion-of-the-console-in-a-windows-native-c-cons)

For Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43075/how-to-change-the-contents-of-a-line-on-the-terminal-as-opposed-to-writing-a-new