# carriage return not working in xcode console c++

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I want to output the time and loop it so the time is constantly being updated without outputting the same line again and again so I thought id overwrite the line by using the carriage but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why, is it to do with Xcode??  I have previously read other posts on stack overflow regarding \r and tried to adapt the answers to my code but none of the solutions seemed to work nor are they related to ios/Xcode. I am also assuming that the problem may have something to do with the Xcode console, being as how it is not a terminal (however I am not to sure)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //Loop Forever
    for(;;){
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        time ( &rawtime );
        timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
        cout << "The current date/time is: " << asctime(timeinfo) << "\r";
    }
    return 0;
}


output:

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017

The current date/time is: Fri Feb 10 17:20:43 2017
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? are you trying to print each one on a new line? or are you trying to clear the current line and overwrite the line with the updated time?

Comment: sorry, i should have been more specific, i am trying to clear the current line and overwrite

Comment: It's better to copy paste the output of your program directly into the question rather than uploading an Image to the output. I suggest you edit the question to do so.

Comment: i have edited it now, is that better?

Comment: Format the output as code

Comment: So you're trying to update the first line every second?

Comment: See Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350254/how-do-rewrite-a-line-of-text-in-a-console-project-c/28350285#28350285

Comment: And Here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508490/how-can-i-erase-the-current-line-printed-on-console-in-c-i-am-working-on-a-lin

Comment: yes thats what I am trying to do, thank you alex, I am kinda new to stack overflow

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do rewrite a line of text in a console project? c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350254/how-do-rewrite-a-line-of-text-in-a-console-project-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is due to this function `asctime(timeinfo)`. If you dump the hex output of the output of this function, it contains `'\n'`. Here is an example

```
467269204665622031302032333A33343A303620323031370A
```

Please notice the last 2 characters. It is 0x0A which means it has `'\n'` at the end of the string. So whatever you try it won't fix the issue till you fix this string. You need to delete `\n` character from the string and then adding `'\r'` will suffice your need. Here is my solution (I am mixing C code in C++ as `asctime()` returns `char *`). You can find alternate solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void remove_all_chars(char* str, char c) {
    char *pr = str, *pw = str;
    while (*pr) {
        *pw = *pr++;
        pw += (*pw != c);
    }
    *pw = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //Loop Forever
    for(;;){
        time_t rawtime;
        struct tm * timeinfo;
        time ( &rawtime );
        timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
        char *timeString = asctime(timeinfo);
        remove_all_chars(timeString, '\n');
        cout << "The current date/time is: " << timeString << "\r";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With original code:

[image]

With my modified code

[image]

Comment: I have already tried a similar approach and I have tried what you suggested but neither of them seemed to work

Comment: ah thats my problem, im using the Xcode console, I dont know how to send programs to terminal, ill look into that now, thank you for your help

Comment: Lets say the above program is in file test.cpp. Go to terminal and do "clang++ test.cpp" then you can just do ./a.out to run

Comment: Added images to explain this better

Comment: i tested it in the terminal there and it works perfect! that was driving me mad haha thank you so much, do u think its just a problem so with the xcode console??

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes to get the correct return you need to use the \r\n and when using escape characters I believe you need double quotes and not single quotes or it is rendered as a literal. Make sure you are using the proper return type for your OS - [\r\n , \r , \n what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15433188/r-n-r-n-what-is-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: Or just use `std::endl`...but the OP is not trying to print a newline, the intent is to overwrite the text of the current line

Comment: Understood, I assumed the new line was what he was going for but he was getting the wrong type but i now understand that was the actual output included above and not his desired result.